# Reverse Lottery Ball Odds

Tags: probability

This is a question I have been trying to solve (for a fantasy hockey draft) that I am struggling with.

There are 10 balls in a random distributer numbered 1-10. Each ball represents a team in the league. The first ball to get picked would then be assigned the 10th spot in the draft and so on. Ball #10 can go back into the distributor 4 times, Ball #9 can go back in 3 times, Ball #8 can go back in 2 times and Ball #7 can go back in once. Balls #1-6 cannot go back in and therefore are immediately assigned that draft position. For example, if the first ball picked is a ball #7-10, the ball goes back in and the pick is redone. If the first ball picked is a ball # 1-6, they are assigned the draft position of 10th and the draw moves to draft position 9.

My question is what is the probability distribution of ball #10 (what is the percentage breakdown on which draft pick it gets) and so on for the other balls. To be perfectly honest I don't know where to start with that many moving variables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it as a Markov chain.  The states are the number of times $7-10$ have been picked and which balls are still in play.  It is a mess. I would just do a simulation and see how it comes out.  Clearly $1-6$ will be biased low and $10$ will be biased high, but it is hard to guess how much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted Ross in comments, exact solution is possible, while being intimidating. At the same time simulation is quite simple here, so running it one can get approximately following distributions:
[image: draft position #10]

[image: draft position #7]

[image: draft position #4]

[image: draft position #1]

Links on the rest of plots:

[[draft position #9]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGlav.jpg)
[[draft position #8]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEpO3.jpg)
[[draft position #6]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUUni.jpg)
[[draft position #5]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG3qQ.jpg)
[[draft position #3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUN3n.jpg)
[[draft position #2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUgL5.jpg)

Results obtained over running $10^5$ simulations.

Comment: Good results. Let's find a formula , helped by this 1/2 for 10 at the 1st place

Comment: @igael: I run several more iterations and it seems that probability of $10th$ ball at draft position #1 is more than $0.5$. The same for $1-6$ in draft position #8 - average is slightly bigger than $0.15$

Comment: I have this for the 10 distribution : "502747  266664  132310   58928   24482    9728    3626    1152     307      56 1000000" and this for the 1st place ( last attributed ) : "8434 8333 8588 8532 8503 8487  43515  127296  275565  502747 1000000". I'll try more now

Comment: exact, it's probably not 1/2 : with 100.000.000 : distribution of 10 : "50320392 26641301 13223821  5873922  2458503   975863   355889   115790    29695     4822" and the draft distribution 8 : 15068112 15071241 15055634 15057803 15046741 15037932 6978917 2054665 513165 115790